# google cloud - block incoming connections

Tags: networking, firewall, google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to block incoming connections to Google Cloud from a specific set of IP addresses?

Our company website is hosted on GCE and I'd like to block few IP addresses that are currently scraping our site. I couldn't find any options in the "Firewall" section in the GCE console.

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The firewall in GCE is used to 'allow' incoming traffic and unfortunately cannot be used to create 'block' rules. In summary, almost everything is blocked by default and you need to create rules to allow incoming traffic.

Instead, you can use the firewall on the VM itself. For example, if you're running a Linux instance you can look into `iptables`. [Here's a Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) on it, but I highly recommend you go through the man pages for details. This way you can create a rule to block one particular IP address for example.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing (using iptables). Thanks.

Comment: This solution is no longer necessary. It is now possible to block incoming traffic from a specific set of IP addresses under **VPC network** > **Firewall rules** in the Google Cloud Platform console. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49938304/4387229

Comment: Can you please change the accepted answer, @Alex2326?

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to block incoming traffic from a specific set of IP addresses under **VPC network** > **Firewall rules** in the Google Cloud Platform console. This means you can apply the one blocking rule to all your GCE instances that are on the same VPC network.

Here's the blocking rule settings I used to block all traffic from a specific set of IP addresses:

**Priority:** 900 (needs to be a lower number than your allow rules so it overrides your allow rules when matching a blocked IP address)

**Direction:** Ingress

**Action on match:** Deny

**Source filters:**
**IP ranges:** A comma separated list of IP addresses or IP ranges

**Protocols and ports:** Deny all

**Enforcement:** Enabled

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, the most efficient way to block is by using an ipset, which is quicker than using iptables.

Commands:

```
sudo ipset -N BLOCK nethash
sudo ipset -q -A BLOCK 35.192.0.0/12
sudo ipset -q -A BLOCK 35.208.0.0/12
sudo ipset -q -A BLOCK 35.240.0.0/13
sudo ipset -q -A BLOCK 35.224.0.0/12
sudo ipset -q -A BLOCK 35.184.0.0/13
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set BLOCK src -j DROP
```

1. The first line creates a list of IPs and ranges in ipset, called BLOCK
2. The next five lines block Google Cloud IP ranges to the BLOCK ipset
3. The last line tells iptables to block any requests to or from any address that matches the BLOCK ipset

As far as I know those are Google Cloud's IP ranges as of writing. You can check them by WHOIS-ing them; though I think the only changes that are likely to happen is more IPs are added rather than current ones are droppe.